# Tampermonkey, Userscripts add URL to script with POP UP

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I'm using tampermonkey to run some scripts on a website.

Now I'm trying to make it that whenever u go to a certain page("example.com")

U will get a pop up where u can press yes or no.

Yes = Add the URL to the tampermonkey script User includes (the script will than run on this URL)
No = Don't add

Couldn't find documentation about this subject on the internet so I was wondering if someone has any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried using a `confirm()` ?

Comment: yes opening the pop up isn't the problem. Adding the URL to the userscript is what I don't know how to solve

Comment: i didn't think a script could change it's settings via script...

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to settle for a workaround since I don't think you can dynamically add rules, i.e. a URL to include.

Add the following to your user script header.

```
// @match *
// @grant GM_setValue
// @grant GM_getValue
```

The following code will include a URL.

```
function includeUrl(url) {
  var includes = JSON.parse(GM_getValue('includes')) || [];
  includes.push(url);
  GM_setValue('includes', JSON.stringify(includes));
}
```

The following code will determine whether the script should run.

```
function shouldRun() {
  var includes = JSON.parse(GM_getValue('includes'));
  if (includes) {
    var url = window.location.href;
    if (includes.indexOf(url) > -1) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Stitch them together

```
// prompt user if they want to include Url (use includeUrl)

if (!shouldRun()) return; // prevent execution    

// your code ...
```